# how to change specific string order in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Running Win 7 with Python 2.7. I want to change the string:

- `‘%01#WDD00300003010F123456’`

to:

- `‘%01#WDD0030000301120F5634’`

Therefore I want to change the last 8 characters from `0F123456` to `120F5634`. How could I write code to achieve that？

Comment: Please also show what you've tried before posting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chop off the bit where you want to swap the digits around:

```
s = "%01#WDD00300003010F123456"
sb, se = s[:-8], s[-8:]
```

Now define a function to break `se` into digit pairs:

```
def digit_pairs(s):
    return [s[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(s),2)]
```

and a function to switch the pairs around:

```
def switch(s):
    for i in range(1,len(s),2):
        yield  s[i]
        yield  s[i-1]
```

Then you can do

```
>>> ''.join(switch(digit_pairs(se)))
'120F5634'
```

Answer (score 0):

List slicing will work if you know how many characters you want to replace.

From IDLE:

```
>>> longstr = "this is a somewhat lengthy string"
>>> longstr[:5]
'this '
>>> longstr[5:]
'is a somewhat lengthy string'
>>> longstr[:-5]
'this is a somewhat lengthy s'
>>> longstr = longstr[:-6] + "road"
>>> longstr
'this is a somewhat lengthy road'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def shuffle(strVal):
    val = strVal[-8:]
    temp = [val[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(val), 2)]
    res = "" 
    for i in zip(temp[::2], temp[1::2]):
        res = res + "".join([i[1], i[0]])

    return strVal[:-8] + res

s =  "%01#WDD00300003010F123456"
print shuffle(s)
```

**Output:**

```
%01#WDD0030000301120F5634
```

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt using `re` module:

```
import re

s = """‘%01#WDD00300003010F123456’"""

print(re.sub(r'(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})’', r'\2\1\4\3’', s))
```

Prints:

```
‘%01#WDD0030000301120F5634’
```

Comment: How is this different to my answer?

Comment: @taras If you say so. I wanted to show OP how to match HEX values since that's what the substrings looks like, rather than just matching anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: Replace will work for you.

```
a="%01#WDD00300003010F123456"
a.replace("0F123456","120F5634")
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved as blow:

```
str1 = '%01#WDD00300003010F123456'
ol
str2 = str1[:-8]

str3 = str2 + '120F5634'
print(str1)
print(str3)
```